# Jython, where should i put my .py files

Tags: java, python, path, jython

I am really new to Java/Eclipse and I am trying to do this [Jython tutorial](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonMonthly/Articles/September2006/1).

I do not understand where I should put my python files the IDE's tree directory structure. I've tried placing the file in several locations without success (I must be missing something). This is the error message I get:

```
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Employee
```

My tree directory structure for this tutorial is as follows:

```
JythonTest
---src
------jyinterface
---------factory
------------EmployeeFactory.java
------------Employee.py
---------interfaces
------------EmployeeType.java
------------Employee.py
---------Main.java
---------Employee.py
---Employee.py
---lib
------jython-2.5.2.jar
------Employee.py
```

---

***EDIT*** : So I'm partially answering myself, for the first part I have found [this link](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/jython_course_03.html#example-a-possible-organization-on-disk) with explanations of the same kind of situation, and it works!

---

The remaining issue is, how will I handle the import path of my future python libraries, are there any tricks? It seems that I will have to use something like:

```
PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
sys.path.append(new PyString("isItHereThatIShouldPointToJython-2.5.2.jar???"));
```

Is there any way to set a relative path or something installation independent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> run:
>   Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named Employee
>   C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

I tried two things when  I had this issue. I stopped using the standalone jar, due to cmd errors. Then when trying this code

```
https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonMonthly/Articles/October2006/3
```

Instead of placing the Employee.py in the jyinterface.interfaces package I placed it free floating in the src folder. (I am using Netbeans with py plug in)

Answer (score -1):

If you're working with Eclipse, I would encourage you to look at the [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) plugin.  We use this extensively for Jython development in a complex environment, and it takes care of everything for us, in terms of where to put .py files, or structuring packages.